# UICollectionViewReusableView Error: Selecting one header sometimes triggers the other

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionreusableview

`UICollectionViewReusableView` Error: Selecting one header sometimes triggers the other header

`UICollectionView` has 2 sections. Each has a header with a button that changes `BOOL` state of either `textDeleteActive` or `imageDeleteActive`, then reloads a section. These are used to show whether the Delete button on each cell is hidden or not. But if I alternate and, after touching one button, touch the other, then it seems to link them. Afterwards touching the second button triggers both `BOOL` vars to change. This is only resolved if the first button is touched again to unlink it somehow. I cannot figure out why or how there is a link.

Code (with most unrelated code removed):

Both `UICollectionReusableView` header views and both `UICollectionViewCell` cells have `@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet deleteButton`. They of course each have an actual UIButton.

myUICollectionViewController:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL textDeleteActive;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL imageDeleteActive;

- (void)TextHeaderDeleteButtonDynamicHandler
{
    NSLog(@"texthead");
    self.textDeleteActive = !self.textDeleteActive;
    [self.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1]];
}
- (void)ImageHeaderDeleteButtonDynamicHandler
{
    NSLog(@"imagehead");
    self.imageDeleteActive = !self.imageDeleteActive;
    [self.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    long fRow = [indexPath row];
    switch ([indexPath section]) {
        case 0:
            if (true) {

                HCSShortCutTextViewCell *theCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyShortCut" forIndexPath:indexPath];


                if (self.imageDeleteActive) {
                    theCell.deleteButton.hidden = NO;
                } else {
                    theCell.deleteButton.hidden = YES;
                }


                [theCell.deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(ImageCellDeleteButtonDynamicHandler:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                return theCell;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if (true) {

                HCSCustomViewCell *theCustCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCustom" forIndexPath:indexPath];

                //no image

                if (self.textDeleteActive) {
                    theCustCell.deleteButton.hidden = NO;
                } else {
                    theCustCell.deleteButton.hidden = YES;
                }


                [theCustCell.deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(TextCellDeleteButtonDynamicHandler:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                return theCustCell;
                }
            break;
        default:
            return nil;
            break;
    }
}
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //handled by the storyboard segue
}

- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
        switch ([indexPath section]) {
            case 0:
                if (true) {
                    HCSMyHeaderReusableView *theCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                    theCell.titleLabel.text = @"Image Shortcuts";
                    NSLog(@"ima");
                    [theCell.deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(ImageHeaderDeleteButtonDynamicHandler) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                    return theCell;
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if (true) {
                    HCSMyHeaderReusableView *theCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                    theCell.titleLabel.text = @"Text Shortcuts";
                    NSLog(@"tex");
                    [theCell.deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(TextHeaderDeleteButtonDynamicHandler) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                    return theCell;
                }
                break;
            default:
                return nil;
                break;
        }
    } else
        return nil;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //set defaults
    self.textDeleteActive = NO;
    self.imageDeleteActive = NO;
}

- (void)TextCellDeleteButtonDynamicHandler:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    NSLog(@"textcell");
    [self deleteItemAndReloadCollectionView:sender event:event defaultsKey:@"textShortcuts"];
}
- (void)ImageCellDeleteButtonDynamicHandler:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    NSLog(@"imagecell");
    [self deleteItemAndReloadCollectionView:sender event:event defaultsKey:@"shortcuts"];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with a hack. Made two delete buttons and had only one appear per each so that `addTarget:` was used on different buttons so no multiple target selectors being used on one single button. Apparently the target carries over through reuse of dequeueing.